# Get index and object from ObservableCollection<t>.Where

Tags: c#, parsing, search

I hope this title isn't missleading. It was kind of hard to come up with one.

Anyhow. I'm filtering through a list which looks like this:

```
public class Track
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public Int64 duration { get; set; }
    public List<string> genre { get; set; }
    public string searchpath { get; set; }
    public Album album { get; set; }
    public string artistname { get; set; }
    public bool IsPlaying { get; set; }

}
```

And I'm trying to get an object and it's index in my observable collection based on it's "searchpath" variable. Here's what I have:

```
foreach (var p in Playlist.Where(p => (p.searchpath == file))) //.Where is an extension method
                        SongChanged.Invoke(p);
```

This only gives me the object, but not it's index in the Playlist-Collection.

Here's my problem: There might be copies of songs in the Playlist, so even a index number won't really do much.
So I thought it might be a good idea to take three objects of track. The previous one in the list, the one I'm trying to find the index of and the track which is next in the list.

How would I use these three objects to find the middle-one's index?

I hope you understand what I'm trying to ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a projection first - select all items along with their index as an anonymous object and then perform `Where` to get the right items.

```
var lists = Playlist.Select((p, i) => new { Track = p, Index = i })
                    .Where(p => p.Track.searchpath == file);
foreach (var l in lists)
{
    SongChanged.Invoke(l.Track); 
    // do what you need to do with an index using l.Index
}
```